# What's going on here with zero divisors and invertibility?

Tags: functional-analysis

I was trying to prove:

If $\Omega$ is compact Hausdorff then $f\in C(\Omega)$ is a left topological zero divisor if and only if $f$ is not invertible.

Showing $\implies$ is easy. This is an exercise in Murphy's book. When I couldn't prove the other direction I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/467435/73381). I would of course contact the author but ufortunately the account was deleted. Now let $\Omega$ be the closed complex unit disk. Then although in the linked thread the example uses the disk algebra the argument still works in $C(\Omega)$, thereby providing a counterexample to what I wanted to prove.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fill in the argument why if $||f_n(z) \cdot z||_{C(\overline{B})} \to 0$ then $||f_n(z)||_{C(\overline{B})} \to 0$. It uses strongly the fact that $f_n$ are holomorphic (using the maximum principle). If you don't assume that $f_n$ are holomorphic but merely continuous, you can take $f_n$ to be some continuous function such that $f_n(z) = 1$ for $|z| \geq \frac{2}{n}$, $0 \leq f_n(z) \leq 1$ for $\frac{1}{n} \leq |z| \leq \frac{2}{n}$ and $f_n(z) = 0$ for $|z| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ and then $||f_n(z) \cdot z||_{C(\overline{B})} \leq \frac{2}{n}$ so $||f_n(z) \cdot z||_{C(\overline{B})} \to 0$ but $||f_n(z)||_{C(\overline{B})} \nrightarrow 0$ because it doesn't even converge pointwise to the zero function.